# citrix workspace not working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop, workspaces, citrix

I have installed Citrix workspace from [Citrix Workspace app 2006 for Linux](https://www.citrix.com/en-in/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html). It is installed properly and I am also getting a login page. But, after pressing submit it is throwing error as below :

```
This site can’t be reached. The web page at nsgcepa://nsgcepa might be
temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
address. ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

How can we solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprising, installing the tarball package works ! But debian package was giving the error .

1. Go to [Citrix Workspace app 2006 for Linux](https://www.citrix.com/en-in/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html)
2. Scroll down and goto Tarball section
3. Download *Citrix Workspace app for Linux (x86_64)* package . This is for 64-bits system. If your system is 32-bits then download the package below this one (*x86* version)
4. Create a empty folder and put the dowloaded `tar.gz` file there
5. Run `tar xvfz file.tar.gz`
6. You will see a file named `setupwfc` (something like this)
7. Run it as `./setupwfc`
8. Follow the instruction
9. At last it will ask for usb package something . Just skip that
10. Now search citrix in dash
11. Now it should work

Comment: Can you please let me know how you installed the tarball package. And what file did you use ?

Comment: I have mentioned in my answer the steps .

Comment: Can you confirm whether the microphone is picked up in Citrix Workspace?